# How to share common log file among multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-webflux, java.util.concurrent

Can we share same log file among multiple threads reading and writing into it.

Is it a good idea to dump messages in Deque like concurrent collection first and then periodically dump data from deque to log file.

Please share Any example/ pointers for best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by threads you are referring to applications / programs running either on the same machine or in a distributed environment and not multiple threads within the same application.

Then ...

- If you are using Log4J as your logging framework you could implement your logging through a `SocketAppender` (see [Log4J appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)). Then your various applications could connect to a separate "logging" service you've written to consolidate all the logs into a single file.
- Another alternative is to have all your applications register as producers on a specific queue (something like RabbitMQ), where logs lines are posted as messages. Then you can again have a separate consumer, which consumes the messages and writes them to your log.

Comment: Threads are running in same application and same physical server. Like we created fixedThreadpool of 10 threads and all running in parallel and the machine have enough cores to run all threads in parallel at same time.

Comment: Then just use a logging framework such as [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)

Comment: I can't use that due to some restrictions. I am trying to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue to collect data from Threads and create a dedicated thread to keep polling this queue and dump data in file ... let me know other ways to achieve concurrency in this case.

Comment: @Himanshu, did you come right? If so, please mark it as resolved by checking the tick. Tx